# Difference between xgboost and py-xgboost?

Tags: python, xgboost

I have developed my model using xgboost package in Jupyter Notebook. 
When we are trying to take it over to the production environment, the client suggested using py-xgboost which is available in their environment.

But in Jupyter Notebook I'm unable to import or install py-xgboost package, since it is not present.

Anyone can help me with this query?

Answer (score 3):

I have the same question.  It appears that xgboost and py-xgboost in the conda-forge repo are the same package, and both can be imported using

```
import xgboost as xgb
```

However, there are CPU-only versions of those two packages, and other versions which may (?) include GPU support. The pip (PyPi) version of xgboost includes GPU support is usually more up-to-date than both of the above packages on conda-forge.

I had used only the pip version in a conda environment, but then I installed tpot, which has py-xgboost (CPU, e.g. 1.5.1-cpu_py39ha538f94_2) as a dependency. So, now I have both pip xgboost and py-xgboost installed in the same environment.  When I import xgboost and check version, it matches the pip version.

One way to get a definitive answer would be to post a question on the xgboost github page.

Comment: Indeed, in the thread below the author confirmed that the rapidsai sourced py-xgboost comes with GPU acceleration as opposed to xgboost: 
https://discuss.xgboost.ai/t/xgboost-version-not-compiled-with-gpu-support/1936/2

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you've tried this, but if it is installed, in Jupyter, you import py-xgboost as

```
import xgboost
```

If it is not installed, you in a conda or pip environment?

If not installed and you're using pip, have you tried pip or pip3 install?

```
pip install xgboost
```

or

```
pip3 install xgboost
```

If not installed and you're using conda,

```
conda install -c conda-forge xgboost
```

Sorta tangential, a really easy way (if your GPU is Pascal or higher) you can install [RAPIDS via conda](https://rapids.ai/start.html#get-rapids) guided by this interactive graphic.  It will not just install xgboost and py-xgboost, but enable your whole pydata stack take advantage of the GPU acceleration.

Comment: Yes, I performed the same as you mentioned above, but it didn't helped me to resolve the issue.

Comment: that's really weird.  you are trying "import xgboost" and not "import py-xgboost", right?